# Почему и куда затекает нога?

Tags: значение-слов

Когда у меня немеет конечность от неудобной позы, мы говорим, что у нас затекла нога или рука. А интересно, почему, собственно, затекла? Куда затекла?
Со своей стороны могу предположить, что подразумевается затекшая к нее и застоявшаяся кровь, но, возможно, смысл другой.
Так вот, почему нога или рука затекает?

Answer (score 1):

Вы правильно предполагаете. Словарь Академии Российской толкует слово именно так :

> **Затекаю** ... Заплываю, наполняюсь жиром, кровью или другою влажностию. Говорится о теле животном. *Затекли глаза. Затекли ноги.*